How to remove the default menus and buttons from Unity editor?
Is it possible to remove default menu buttons like the Play Pause buttons from the Unity editor? Also, can I add custom dropdowns in addition to the default dropdowns like Layers and Layout?
Check the attached image for more clarification Ref mage
I tried researching the Editor scripting API but I dont find what I am looking for.

Not as far as I know. There might be some hack method (maybe using Reflection), but there might be nasty side-effects so I don't recommend trying (not to mention it'd take a long time and its counter-productive). There have been some people asking for it but they didn't seem a priority. I think you can use the ProductBoard for UnityEditor to suggest it as an idea.

don't know if you can remove already existing buttons or not but for adding new buttons Unity Toolbar Extender is a very good solution.
here's a sample code:

    [InitializeOnLoad]
    public class ToolbarExtend {
        static ToolbarExtend()
        {
            ToolbarExtender.LeftToolbarGUI.Add(OnToolbarGUILeft);
            ToolbarExtender.RightToolbarGUI.Add(OnToolbarGUIRight);
        }

        static void OnToolbarGUILeft()
        {
            GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();

            if(GUILayout.Button(new GUIContent("Scenes", "Show Scenes"))) {
                PingAndSelect(AssetDatabase.LoadMainAssetAtPath("Assets/Scenes/LoginScene.unity"));
            }
        }

        static void OnToolbarGUIRight()
        {
            
            if(GUILayout.Button(new GUIContent("Build Folder", "Open Build Path")))
            {
                BuildNamingTool.Reset();
                Debug.Log(BuildNamingTool.BuildFolder);
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", BuildNamingTool.BuildFolder.Replace("/", @"\"));
            }
            
            GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();
        }


        private static void PingAndSelect(Object target)
        {
            EditorGUIUtility.PingObject(target);
            Selection.activeObject = target;
        }
    }

and Unity Circular Menu is a good solution for quick access to some options.
here's a sample code:
        [CircularMenu(path: "Project Setting", icon: "Settings")]
        public static void OpenProjectSetting()
        {
            SettingsService.OpenProjectSettings("Project/Player");
        }

        [CircularMenu(path: "PlayerPrefs", icon: "Preset.Context")]
        public static void OpenPlayerPrefs()
        {
            EditorApplication.ExecuteMenuItem("Window/PlayerPrefs Editor");
        }
        
        [CircularMenu(path: "Clear PlayerPrefs", icon: "TreeEditor.Trash")]
        public static void ClearPlayerPrefs()
        {
            PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll();
            PlayerPrefs.Save();
        }

